# IOS Storing state of UI elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, interface-builder

I have an IOS app with multiple UIIMageView objects and wondering what would be the best way to remember their locations if the user killed the app or if they wanted to save that particular layout for future use.

I'm a beginner at this so looking for the simplest and most effective method. The only thing I can think of at the moment is to extract CGPoint location and tag of each object and save to NSUserDefaults or something but i'm hoping theres an easier way...

Comment: have you try State Preservation and Restoration https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html

Comment: Indeed, you should look at state preservation rather than storing data in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something as simple as storing `CGPoint`s, I'd recommend using `NSUserDefaults`, because you can very easy manage the data in it using a `NSMutableArray`.

You can go for `Core Data` and then maybe integrate `iCloud`, however `NSUserDefaults` keeps it simple.

Since your problem is to do with the state of the app, I'd recommend reading [what Apple has to say about it.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html)